# elastic search aggregation on more than one field

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am new to elastic search and I want to implement a specific use case on it. I want to have a multi field sum aggregation. I will try to explain on example:
I have following objects inserted into es index:

```
{"a":"aval", "b":"bval", "c":"cval", "aggcount":100}
```

where a,b and are strings and aggcount is an int.
Now let's assume I have following records indexed:

```
{"a":"aa", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":10}
{"a":"aa", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":11}
{"a":"aa", "b":"b", "c":"c", "aggcount":1}
{"a":"a", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":12}
{"a":"a", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":5}
```

Now I would like to group records by fields a,b and c and sum their aggcount values, so for the previous records I would get following result:

```
{"a":"aa", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "count":21}
{"a":"aa", "b":"b", "c":"c", "count":1}
{"a":"a", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":17}
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this? I tried nested significant_terms and sum aggregations but I didn't succeed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sub-aggregations:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_a": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "a"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggs_b": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "b"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "aggs_c": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "c"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "summing": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "aggcount"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test data and results:

```
POST /test_index/test_type/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"a":"aa", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":10}
{"index":{}}
{"a":"aa", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":11}
{"index":{}}
{"a":"aa", "b":"b", "c":"c", "aggcount":1}
{"index":{}}
{"a":"a", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":12}
{"index":{}}
{"a":"a", "b":"bb", "c":"cc", "aggcount":5}
```

gives:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "aggs_a": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "aa",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "aggs_b": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "bb",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "aggs_c": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "cc",
                                 "doc_count": 2,
                                 "summing": {
                                    "value": 21
                                 }
                              }
                           ]}},
                     {
                        "key": "b",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "aggs_c": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "c",
                                 "doc_count": 1,
                                 "summing": {
                                    "value": 1
                                 }
                              }
                           ]}]}
            },
            {
               "key": "a",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "aggs_b": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "bb",
                        "doc_count": 2,
                        "aggs_c": {
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                           "buckets": [
                              {
                                 "key": "cc",
                                 "doc_count": 2,
                                 "summing": {
                                    "value": 17
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
}}]}}]}}}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I did but it is super slow and I am not sure how to navigate through results, currently I am only receiving one result - I mean there is only one top lvl aggregation, and there should be manym I dont know how to access next

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the client you are trying to use. You haven't mentioned anything about that

Comment: I am just trying to write a query with marvel plugin called sense. As I said I am quite a noobie, is my approach incorrect?

Comment: I used Sense, as well :-). Updated my answer with what output I get when I use your exact data and my query.

Comment: yeah i saw, thanks for the help. The problem is that i have such a big index that it doesn't seem to return all possible aggregations

Comment: You can control how many buckets are returned by specifying `"size": 100` for each `"terms"` aggregation (by default ES returns 10 buckets). So, something like this: `"terms": {
                "field": "c", "size": 40
              }`

Comment: i just noticed i am using significat_terms instead of terms, need to spot a difference, thanks anyway!